# CCRotateBy not completing

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a simple `CCRotateBy` action in a sequence; it is followed by a call to another method which confirms that the CCRotateBy completed (otherwise, that `CCCallFunc` would not get called in the sequence if CCRotateBy didn't complete):

```
-(void)correctRotation{
    if (self.rotationAmount){
    CCLOG(@"correcting rotation inside: %i",self.buildNum);
    CCRotateBy*second=[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1 angle:-self.rotationAmount];
    CCEaseBackInOut*bounce2=[CCEaseBackInOut actionWithAction:second];
    CCCallFunc*func=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stabilize)];
    CCSequence*seq=[CCSequence actions:bounce2,func, nil];
    [self runAction:seq];
    }
}

-(void)stabilize{
        CCLOG(@"stabilize before rotation: %i for %i",self.rotationAmount,self.buildNum);
    self.rotationAmount=0;
        CCLOG(@"stabilize after rotation: %i for %i",self.rotationAmount,self.buildNum);    
}
```

The CCLog statements are confirming that the rotation should be happening, and that the angle of the rotation is not nil (it is always an integer). These logs also show that the `CCSequence` is completing. However, the sprite is not rotating on the screen. I've been pouring over this code for hours trying to figure out what could be going wrong. If the sprite's actions were being stopped, then these 3 log statements would not complete, right?

Comment: strange ... hmmm , have had a similar one in the past with another interval action (cocos version 99.4 at the time).  Did you try to 'shake' the system and attempt a CCRotateTo self.rotation + self.rotationAmount ? that fixed it for me ...

Comment: i didn't know there was a rotation property on CCSprite; it's not in the class reference. This is supposed to be the degrees of rotation of the sprite?

Comment: CCSprite like most (all?) objects in cocos derive from CCNode, which has rotation property. I just did a quick test, it is settable. Also (this may sound silly) have you verified that self.isRunning is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tassinari says try removing the bounce function.

This is from the cocos2d api reference

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/1.1.0/interface_c_c_ease_back_in_out.html

```
Warning:
This action doesn't use a bijective function. Actions like Sequence might have an
unexpected result when used with this action.
```

Comment: useful, thanks, but not the cause of the issue. i took out the ease action, using just the straight rotate action, but issue remains and is identical

Comment: when are you calling the correctRotation function? I just test a similar code on my project and works fine, so maybe the issue is when you call the function. Are you sure that rotationAmount is > 0? Try with a fixed number just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Quick look but you're not calling CCRotateBy in your sequence.  The 'second' action is not in the sequence.

Comment: Sorry, just saw its in your bounce action,  maybe remove the ease in/out while you debug.